# Notepad++ appears to ignore the "Replace by Space" setting

Tags: notepad++

I am trying to get notepad++ to insert a tab instead of 4 spaces when I press the tab key.

Other questions I have seen in this regard all appear to want to do the opposite. But I want tab indentation.

I went into Settings -> Preferences -> Language -> Tab Settings and unchecked "Replace by Space". However, pressing the tab key still leads to 4 spaces being inserted. I've tried changing the Tab Size field from 4 to 1, to no avail.
I have also tried choosing some of the other presets. For a few of these I end up with rather more than 4 spaces. But in no case do I get a tab.
What could be the issue?

[Image of Menu Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c4bM8.png)

*Edit 1: I am using Notepad++ v7.8.2 (64-bit)
*Edit 2: With "Replace by Space" unchecked and tab size of 4, showing tabs and spaces, in my existing file (made on another computer) I get 4 spaces as shown below:

[Image of the behaviour in existing file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3fKcq.png)

If I make a new notepad++ file and indent, I seem to get a really small tab. However, it's a tab, which is already a step forward.

[Image of the behaviour in a new file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qT0Er.png)

Comment: Works for me. How do you check that there are spaces and not tabulations?

Comment: The image shows a tab size of 1. What is shown after "menu => View => Show Symbol => Show white space and tab" is ticked?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my issue as follows:
1) In Settings -> Preferences I went to the "Auto-Completion" menu. I turned off both "Auto-indent" and "Enable auto completion on each input"

2) I went Plugins -> Plugins Admin and installed the "Python Indent" plugin. Next, don't forget to hover over Plugins -> Python Indent and click "Enable"

This resolved the issue completely.

Comment: it didn't work for me